# if and elif statements- are they correct and match what the table is asking

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

The ValueError part of my code works well alone but with my if and elif statements it does not work? could someone please explain what I did wrong thank you. The table is linked and my coding is written for you.

[!table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mayZQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mayZQ.png)

```
      pass_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at pass:"))
     defer_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at defer:"))
     fail_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at pass:"))

     if pass_credit==120:
        print("progress")

     elif pass_credit==100:
       print("do not progress-module retriever")

     elif fail_credit>80:
         print("exclude")

     elif pass_credit==80:
        print("do not progress-module retriever")

     elif pass_credit<80:
        print("do not progress-module retriever")


#Start
   while True:
     try:   
           pass_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at pass:"))
           break
    except ValueError as e:
          print ("Bad integer value entered, try again.")

while True:
    try:   
        defer_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at defer:"))
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print ("Bad integer value entered, try again.")

while True:
    try:   
        fail_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at fail:"))
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print ("Bad integer value entered, try again.")

print(f"You entered: {pass_credit=}, {defer_credit=}, {fail_credit=}")
while True:
    try:   
        entry=input("please enter your credits at pass:")
        pass_credit = int(entry)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print (f"You entered: {entry}, which is not an integer, try again.")
#End
```

Comment: _but with my if and elif statements it does not work_ Saying "does not work" is not helpful to understanding the problem.  Instead, tell us what the code actually does.

Comment: traceback error when I want run the code. I type in for example p and expect "bad integer value entered, try again. but it keeps saying line 2, in <module>
    pass_credit=int(input("please enter your credits at pass:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'k'

Comment: The first three input statements do not have `try/except`, so of course they will fail with bad input.  What else did you expect?

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent throughout this code, making it syntactically invalid. Given how sensitive Python is to whitespace (a small change in leading whitespace completely changes the meaning of the code), you really need to edit to make sure it's all correct.

Comment: could you tell me how to correct these issues. I am new to coding

Comment: at the beginning of the code I am asking the user for input